# Multiple Auth in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want to integrate multiple table in authentication, i've gone through these steps:

First I. created a migration:

```
php artisan make:migration createTouristsTable
```

in Migration file:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tourists', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();            
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

run migrate

```
php artisan migrate
```

Tourists Model:

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Tourists extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'tourists';

    protected $fillable = ['email',  'password'];

    protected $hidden = ['password',  'remember_token'];
}
```

i've modified config/auth.php file to add my custom guard "tourists".

```
'guards' => [

    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'tourists'  => [
      'driver'  => 'session',
      'provider' => 'tourists',
    ],

],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'tourists' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model'  => App\Tourists::class,
    ],
]
```

Now in my LoginController I need to specify which guard I want to use:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard('tourists');
    }
}
```

Now, how I create a login and registration form for this Table?

Comment: Why does a guest needs a login? What differentiates a guest from a regular user then?

Comment: I gave a fancy name "Guest". I realize that it is not the best.

Comment: i've replaced guest with tourists.

Comment: I recommend you to have only one table for Users...they are all users after all... and create a table with Roles and then assign the roles to users... This is the best and well known approach to solve the problem you have.

Comment: In this case, the problem remain because I need to switch different registration form by role. Every role must have different fields subscription and different features.

Answer (score 0):

You would create new login and registration pages just like you would any other page. The important difference is having either separate routes for each login/registration page or conditionally rendering partials that contain the forms based on some criteria you define so guests go to guest login and regular users go to regular login.

A third option, in my opinion the best fit for this case, is to use components and slots.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#components-and-slots

The question is, how will you make the determination which page an unauthenticated user should go to?